# How to change default permission for files on amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using amazon s3 for storing files

Every time when I upload file to amazon I change file permission.

How customize default amazon s3 permission?

Comment: Which application do you use to upload files to S3 ?

Comment: I am uploading directly - in Amazone Console